# Does DevDays need a new name?

Tags: discussion, devdays

This was recently asked on the [Stack Exchange blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/se-podcast-04/):

> "Is Stack Overflow Dev Days 2011 the best name for the conference or should we come up with something new?  Is the term “Dev Days” being used by too many conferences?"

So in the spirit of Meta, I decided to ask the question here in the hopes of making it easier to brainstorm.

So... what would *you* suggest for the new name?

Comment: But these are the *real* Dev Days!

Comment: overdevflowdays.

Comment: @Will: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Ivo I *think* I heard about a Microsoft conference named DevDays several years ago. I don't think Stack Overflow was the first to use that name.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I believe Microsoft calls theirs TechDays nowadays, because they have content for more tech people than just developers now.

Comment: @George, you said Stack Exchanges on the blog, but you didn't include it here as an answer...

Answer (score 4):

The Stack Overflow **[Calling Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)**

Comment: Wow... I really like that one!

Answer (score 0):

How about **Stack Overflow Bit Swap**?

Comment: That's two letters away from a lawsuit, right there.

Comment: @glowcoder: I think you mean three letters, and I'm no lawyer, but I see your point.  I'm go try my luck at stackunderflow instead.

Comment: Which letters are those?

Answer (score 0):

I think its stupid, but

### OverDevFlowDays

Similar to heavy flow days, but with 100% more overflow (no, I don't know what that means).

(PascalCased--developers who camelCase should not be welcomed)

Comment: IThoughtThisWasWindowsCaseSinceTheWindowsAPIUsedIt.

Comment: Why can't I downvote my own post?